# How multi-threading can be used in a real time web based application, can i get some scenarios

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, runnable

How multi-threading can be used in a real time web based application, can i get some scenarios.

I am learning Java Multi threading concept, i have worked on java web application.

But never got a chance to work on multi threading, just wanted to know for what kind of operations it can be used.

Comment: While this topic feels like an opinion topic, I offer there are many frameworks in J2EE around ManagedExecutorServices and in JAX-RS there are async methods.  Have you looked at these?

Comment: @PaulBastide I do not think it feels "opinion based", but perhaps, rather, "very broad". He is asking to make him understand some example scenarios where threading could make sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491879/role-of-multithreading-in-web-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you are working with an order system. A user might have multiple orders, an order from eBay, another from Amazon. And you need return his/her orders by his id.

You can get his orders with a single thread:

```
List<Order> getOrders(String userId) {
    getEBayOrders(userId);
    getAmazonOrders(urderId);
}
```

if `getEBayOrders` takes 1 second, `getAmazonOrders` takes 1 second, then you need 2 seconds to return the result.

With 2 threads, you can call `getEBayOrders` and `getAmazonOrders` at the same time, then the user can get his orders in 1 second.